# How to save the clicked position of Alert Dialog so next time when we open previous selected item is highlighted?

Tags: android, dialog, android-alertdialog

I have made a Dialog with radio buttons as:

```
    AlertDialog streamQualityDialog;
    // Strings to Show In Dialog with Radio Buttons
    final CharSequence[] items = {" Low "," High "};

    // Creating and Building the Dialog
    final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

    builder.setTitle("Quality:");

    builder.setSingleChoiceItems(items, -1, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int position) {


            final String channelLinkUrl = LinkConfig.getString(Player.this,
                    LinkConfig.CHANNEL_LINK_URL) + "?";

            switch (position) {
                case 0:

                   new ChannelLinkLoader(Player.this, channel, currentCategory + "").execute(channelLinkUrl + "channelId="
                            + channel.getChannelId() + "&highQuality=off" + "&");
                   break;

                case 1:

                   new ChannelLinkLoader(Player.this, channel, currentCategory + "").execute(channelLinkUrl + "channelId="
                            + channel.getChannelId() + "&highQuality=on" + "&");
                   break;

            }
            streamQualityDialog.dismiss();
        }


    });
    streamQualityDialog = builder.create();
    streamQualityDialog.show();
```

Now dialog opens with radio button choice single and radio button is highlighted when clicked. The main problem is when i open the dialog for second time previously if i have selected any item then i want the radio button to be selected on that item previously selected.

How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

what i did was set  public int selectedElement=-1; and i replaced this

```
builder.setSingleChoiceItems(items, -1, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
```

with

builder.setSingleChoiceItems(items, selectedElement, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()

and inside onClick i set the the position of the selection item like this :

selectedElement = position;

This solved my problem.. But if you want to store the value even after app is closed you can use shared preference for that.

Answer (score 0):

Save a flag in `SharedPreferences`.

If you open the dialog, check for that flag and set the selection accordingly.

If a selection is made, update the flag.